# How is memory allocated for arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, utf-8, blob

I was hoping that the program below would output 40,000 bytes (200 * 200 * 8 bit array or 1 byte) but its outputting `159800` when inserting `200`. Why?

It becomes even more confusing when it outputs `119800` when inserting `10` (`subArray[j][0]=10`) and outputs `79800` when inserting `1` (`subArray[j][0]=1`), even though its always 8 bit array.

If I change `Uint8Array(1)` to `Uint16Array(1)` the values outputted are exactly the same for the same numbers.

**How do arrays work?**

```
let x = 200
let y = 200

const changes =[]
for (let i=0;i<y;i++) {
    const subArray = []
    for (let j=0;j<x;j++) {
        subArray[j] = new Uint8Array(1);
        subArray[j][0]=200
    }
    changes[i]=subArray;
}

console.log(new Blob(changes).size);
```

Comment: Not fully understanding why yet, it seems you're not setting the correct length parameter when instantiating the `Uint8Array` object. `200 * 200 * 8 = 320000`. If you set the length param to 3 (since 200 is 3 numbers), the result will be 319800, which seems to make a whole lot more sense

Comment: @icecub 8 is the number of *bits*, and 200 is just one number.

Comment: @Pointy Exactly. Hence my confusion as to why the result was actually somehow making some sense.

Comment: @icecub yea the weird "different size" thing in the question is indeed explained by the string "200" being 3 characters and the string "1" being one character. (I have not done the arithmetic.)

Comment: did you consider checking what data was in the blob? it's probably written all the numbers in decimal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `subArray` is a plain array which happens to be filled with Uint8Array instances. If you change your code so that it's instead a 200-byte typed array, you get the answer you expect:

```
let x = 200
let y = 200

const changes =[]
for (let i=0;i<y;i++) {
    const subArray = new Uint8Array(200);
    for (let j=0;j<x;j++) {
        subArray[j] = 200;
    }
    changes[i]=subArray;
}

console.log(new Blob(changes).size); // 40000
```

The spec doesn't say what happens if one of the "blob parts" is a plain array of typed arrays. It *might* be converting the array to a string, but how exactly that would happen internally I can't say. (*e*: actually I can, I think; see below.)

What I'm going by is the spec, which says what happens for 3 possibilities in the "blob parts" parameter passed to the Blob constructor (`changes` in your code). Each part can be either:

1. a blob;
2. a buffer source (like a typed array);
3. a string.

So no mention of "plain array filled with whatever".

*edit* — if you do a little experiment, it's clear (well, pretty clear) that it's converting the plain array to a string. That will entail converting each element in the array to a string. When you convert a Uint8Array with a single byte whose value is the number 200, you get the string "200", 3 characters. Of course if you instead initialize with 10, you get "10", and 1 gives you "1". That explains (probably) the fact that the initialization values in your code give you different size answers: it's the difference in the size of the values *as strings*, not bytes.

```
let z = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(z[1]); // 2, as a number
let y = [z];
console.log(y.toString()); // '1,2,3' as a string
y = [z, z];
console.log(y.toString()); // '1,2,3,1,2,3'
```

Comment: So it sucks at determining size because it converts to string?

Comment: @Vishal your "subarray" is a *plain JavaScript array*. The fact that it contains Uint8Array instances does not change anything; the Blob construction process will convert it to a string, because that's all it knows to do with anything other than a blob or a buffer source.

Comment: And note that if you do make an array for the Blob constructor out of *typed* arrays, then it works fine.

Comment: So it sucks at calculating accurate size with subArrays. I get that. Could this be a future  improvement?

Comment: @Vishal well it makes absolutely no attempt to do so; it does not recursively descend into the data structure you pass it.

Comment: I would not plan on things changing any time soon.

Comment: JavaScript not recursively going into it is BS. Not you. I appreciate your help.